# How to tell where highlighted text exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I've got a screen that has an outer frame with some text on it, and then an iframe which shows screens that have text on them. I want to create a custom "File" menu that has items like cut,copy,paste, print, etc. I know that you can execute cut,copy,paste commands by calling

```
document.execCommand("cut");
```

if I want to cut something in the parent frame. And if I want to cut something inside the iframe I can do

```
document.getElementById("myIframe").contentWindow.document.execCommand("cut");
```

Since the File menu is going to be living in the parent, I need to be able to differentiate highlighted text in the parent frame vs the iframe so that I know which javascript code to execute.

Comment: What if there is highlighted text in both parent frame and iframe?

Comment: How would that be possible? As far as I know, when you drag a mouse over to highlight text, you can  only do it in one place at a time.

Comment: You can have text selected in the parent and in the iframe at the same time. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qx2g192f/

Answer (score 0):

If you are selecting text outside input and textareas, in firefox you have `document.getSelection()` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getSelection)) and in IE < 11 you have `document.selection.createRange()` ([docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535869%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Otherwise you need to check for the active element and get the selection from there (if any).

The idea is that you can check for selected text in both places and check which one is empty and execute the command where the selection is.

See [this example](http://help.dottoro.com/ljtfkhio.php) to get the current selection, you can apply something similar to both the parent and the iframe and check which one have some selected text.

Hope this helps!